# Regarding variables in classes and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 10 classes and each class has a variable of type bool.Now i wanted to ask is that if use inheritance and use a single bool variable in parent class and inherit the variable in all the ten classes how much would it save in terms of memory?Is there any difference?

```
class parent
{
    private bool checker{ set;
    get;}
};
class multiply2:parent
{
...
}
class multiply3:parent
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
how much would it save in terms of memory?
```

No thing at all...

```
Is there any difference?
```

They would be almost the same.The child classes may have a tiny overhead because of the inheritance.

Comment: Not only look.You get code reuse and it will make things easier in the future

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only similarity between the classes, then I suggest **not** using inheritance simply to save typing a variable declaration.

On the other hand, if there are other similarities that can be factored out to a super class, then by all means, do it!

Comment: No actually that was the only similarity..thnks

Comment: As Code-Apprentice said there is no reason to use inheritance just to avoid a field declaration(and i also suggest not to use it).